# how to reduce/increase gap between horizontal legends- highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I want to be able to increase/decrease the gap between legends split into 2 cols.
ex:
[image]
my legend is defined as follows:

```
legend: {
       align: 'right',
       itemMarginBottom: 8,
       labelFormatter: function() {//some func},
        itemWidth: 290,
       verticalAlign: 'top',
       useHTML: true,
       x: 95,
       y:80
}
```

is there any marginLeft/Right props to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `legend.itemDistance` property.

> **itemDistance: Number**
>
> In a legend with horizontal layout, the itemDistance defines the pixel distance between each item. Defaults to 20.
>
> *ref: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.itemDistance*